# How to retrieve the search results which contains custom columns from drive using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to search the documents within the drive using the `search` keyword. I am able to get the results with the default columns such as `ID`, `Name`, etc..

However, it doesn't include my custom columns. Any idea how to get the custom columns as well along with the default columns?

This is the REST method used:

```
/v1.0/drives/{driveid}/search(q='Test')?select=custom column1,custom column2
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "custom columns"?

Comment: The document library I created have few new columns such as Classification,Country etc.While I search these fields or the document content using  search,the results I received  displays only the default columns such as ID,Name etc.It never shows me the custom columns I created such as classfication,country etc.

Comment: I wanted the search to display all the fields so that I can use them to display in my search results.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this scenario isn't fully supported at the moment.

Currently, you can search a `Drive` resource using:

```
/v1.0/drives/{id}/root/search(q='{query}')
```

This returns a collection of [`microsoft.graph.driveItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem) resources. The API doesn't fully distinguish between a traditional OneDrive `drive` and a SharePoint Document Library `drive` so it is entirely unaware that a given `DriveItem` happens to also have a corresponding `ListItem`.

A [`ListItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/listitem) is a little different in that it *does* contain a reference to the associated `DriveItem`. So from a given `ListItem`, you can use `$expand` to include both `fields` and `driveItem` data in the result:

```
 /v1.0/sites/root:{path}:/lists/{id}/items?$expand=fields,driveitem
```

The problem here, of course, is that the API doesn't provide a search method for `ListItems`. So while you can get the `DriveItem` from a `ListItem`, it isn't possible to do so via a search query. And since you cannot get a `ListItem` from a `DriveItem`, it isn't possible to use `$expand=fields` with the Drive API's `search(q='uqery')`.

**Edit**

One important clarification, you *can* expand an associated `ListItem` from a `DriveItem` (i.e. `/drives/{id}/root/children?$expand=listItem`). What isn't supported however is doing so from a `/search` query (i.e. `drives/{id}/root/search(q='{query}')?$expand=listItem`).

Comment: Thanks so much Marc ! I hope  this is something MS will add since this is one of the key feature which required to take advantage of the API search functionality fully since getting the desired search results  is one of the common feature to be included in the API

Comment: Thanks Marc ! I see your point,however my requirement is to perform the search(Content or metadata) and retrieve the results using the API.Going to each list item would be not ideal since I afraid it might impact the performance as I have to get each item from the search result and then  go the individual  list item each time

Comment: Hi Marc,For the time being I have used the Rest API to perform my search.It is working as expected however would love to have the Graph API expose the custom search feature.